Nest.js Auth and Passport.js
So basically I am making a Restful api for my project I just started Nest.js
and so far I am liking it.
I like the file system and docs are lovely , also as a beginner would it be helpful to use passport or making custom Middleware for learning purposes.
I tried Passport and its great but i want to learn Nest.js properly and utilize it in other projects.
So is making custom Middleware more preferred when it comes to scalable projects?
